# When using NCurses CDK matrix is it possible to update matrix after call to activateCDKMatrix?

Tags: ncurses, curses, ncurses-cdk

I'd like to have a background thread update certain fields and as a result have the matrix periodically redraw/refresh.

My problem is that if ActivateCDKMatrix has been called this seems to block any updates to the matrix until a user hits `Enter` or `ESC` etc.

Is it possible to force a return from the ActivateCDKMatrix call? Or a possible timeout? Or anyway to update the matrix without the user having to hit a key to return?

Answer (score 1):

The `activateCDKMatrix` function is interactive.  You can do what's asked using `injectCDKMatrix`.

*caveat* — CDK isn't thread-safe.